# Add Elements to Textbox View when in landscape mode

Tags: android, view, android-edittext, landscape-portrait

When you activate an editText and your application is in landscape mode your view will change and all you see is a white screen and your textbox.

I have lots of text boxes the user has to fill with information.
Since the white area is stretched to the full width and height of your screen this can be very confusing. You don't know which textbox is now activated.

Thats why I want to add a textlabel to each portrait view of the editText box.
How could this be done?

Edit:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```

is not a solution because the softkeyboard hides some editText boxes.

Comment: What about the `android:hint`-attribute?

Comment: HAH, I didn't new that. This works for me. Thank you